# Can we use Linq for geting value from collection object in java?

Tags: java, linq, blackberry

now a days i am working on blackberry within that i parse some JSON Array into String and from that i convert it into Hashtable like this

this is my JSON string

```
[ 
  { 
        "StdID":"A1",
  "RollNo":"23",
 "Class":"First"

}, 
{ 
        "StdID":"A2",
  "RollNo":"13",
 "Class":"First"

}, 
{ 
        "StdID":"A3",
  "RollNo":"53",
 "Class":"Second"

}, 
{ 
        "StdID":"A4",
  "RollNo":"33",
 "Class":"Third"

}, 

]
```

and i parse this into hashtable as

```
Hashtable t1=new Hashtable();
t1.put("StdID","A1");
t1.put("RollNo","23");
t1.put("Class","First");
Hashtable t2=new Hashtable();
t2.put("StdID","A2");
t2.put("RollNo","13");
t2.put("Class","First");
Hashtable t3=new Hashtable();
t3.put("StdID","A3");
t3.put("RollNo","53");
t3.put("Class","Second");
Hashtable t4=new Hashtable();
t4.put("StdID","A4");
t4.put("RollNo","33");
t4.put("Class","Third");

Hashtable main=new Hashtable ();

main.put(new Integer(1), t1);
main.put(new Integer(2), t2);
main.put(new Integer(3), t3);
main.put(new Integer(4), t4);
```

So can i/ how can i retrieve the value as

> select students which have First class

so any one can help me? 
is this possible by LINQ ?

Comment: Yes, see my complete response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uhm... yes! But you need this library for Java LINQ stuff: //github.com/nicholas22/jpropel-light

How to do it:

```
import java.util.Hashtable;
import lombok.ExtensionMethod;
import propel.core.utils.Linq;
import java.util.List;
import lombok.Function;

@ExtensionMethod({Linq.class})
public class Main
{

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    Hashtable t1=new Hashtable();
    t1.put("StdID","A1");
    t1.put("RollNo","23");
    t1.put("Class","First");
    Hashtable t2=new Hashtable();
    t2.put("StdID","A2");
    t2.put("RollNo","13");
    t2.put("Class","First");
    Hashtable t3=new Hashtable();
    t3.put("StdID","A3");
    t3.put("RollNo","53");
    t3.put("Class","Second");
    Hashtable t4=new Hashtable();
    t4.put("StdID","A4");
    t4.put("RollNo","33");
    t4.put("Class","Third");

    Hashtable main = new Hashtable();
    main.put(new Integer(1), t1);
    main.put(new Integer(2), t2);
    main.put(new Integer(3), t3);
    main.put(new Integer(4), t4);

    List<Hashtable> result= main.values().where(classEquals("First")).toList();
    for(Hashtable ht : result)
      System.out.println(ht.get("StdID"));
  }


  @Function
  private static Boolean classEquals(Hashtable table, String _class) {
    return table.get("Class") != null && table.get("Class").equals(_class);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

**No.** [LINQ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Integrated_Query) is part of .NET, not Java.

#### See also

- [LINQ for Java tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/346721/linq-for-java-tool/346735#346735)
- [Is there something like LINQ for Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2008149/is-there-something-like-linq-for-java)
- [What is the Java equivalent for LINQ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1217228/)

Answer (score 0):

**No** linq is for *.NET 3.5 or greater* not for *JAVA*

Answer (score 0):

As all are saying there is no LINQ for Java as this is only .NET technology.

But you can use APIs which offer similar functionality, e.g. [quaere](http://quaere.codehaus.org/)

BTW. someonw else also asked a similar question, please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2008149/is-there-something-like-linq-for-java) out.