# Language-Integrated Query (LINQ) for Java

Tags: java, linq, java-8

I found several questions on SO regarding LINQ for Java e.g.

- [LINQ for Java tool](https://stackoverflow.com/q/346721/1944131)
- [Is there something like LINQ for Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2008149/1944131)

However, those questions were asked around year 2008 - 2010. At that time Java language did not support necessary language feature like lambda expressions (as per [Jon Skeet's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/346735/1944131)).

Now when Java8 is about to emerge, and will probably provide features such as Lambda Expressions, do you think it is possible to have an LINQ for Java implementation / project soon?

Did you hear about any project trying to fulfill that gap between Java and C#?

Comment: I don't think you will find anything like the LINQ query syntax in  pure Java, but Java 8 includes something very similar to LINQ fluent syntax (with small variations - where <=> filter, select <=> collect etc.). By the way, Java 8 *will* include lambdas.

Comment: @assylias, would you be able to make your comment as an answer and provide some links to *very similar to LINQ fluent syntax* and to details on lambdas. This is something I was looking for. I am happy to accept that answer. Many thanks for your help!

Comment: Can't right now. See for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14830313/retrieving-a-list-from-a-java-util-stream-stream-in-java8

Comment: If you are looking for LINQ features, that probably won't emerge anytime soon. However, LINQ-to-SQL features can be somewhat well remedied by libraries, the one I used after much research is http://www.querydsl.com/.

Comment: Julian Hyde's Optiq (https://github.com/julianhyde/optiq) is about the closest thing in terms of system operation, if not syntax.